# How to create regex to check user name with numbers and space?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a regex that can check user name in this terms:

- two first letters are in a-z (no numbers allowed).
- numbers after two letters are allowed.
- space is allowed - not in the beginning.
- after the space can be only a-z, but not number/special char (`john 2doe` )), but `john d2oe` is okay.
- those rules above is apply to every word in the string.
- no special characters allow such `~!@#$%^&*()`

This is what I have done so far:

```
 /^([A-Za-z]{2,})/.test('john#~ doe') // true. - not good. it should be false.
```

the first and the second I solve it. but how to do the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one that should work for you

`^([A-z]{2}([A-z0-9]|\s[A-z]{2})*)*$`

but note: your rules have a bit of contradiction in them. This regex does not let the `john d2oe` name, as the first two letters of `d2oe` are not letters. This can be changed by using

`^([A-z]{2}([A-z0-9]|\s[A-z])*)*$`

Here, we define the rules for each word, and then say we will match any amount of them. Each word starts with 2 letters, then is followed by any amount of either any amount of letters and numbers, or a space followed by at least 1 (or in the first statement 2) letter(s).

Take a look [at the tests here](https://regexr.com/57okd), I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
^([a-zA-Z]{2})([a-zA-z0-9]*)([ ]*)([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$
```

Clears:

```regex
john d2oe
jo hnd2oe
```

Fails:

```
john 2doe
j2hn d2oe
 ohn d2oe
```